# Sqoop to import data into HDFS from a CSV

Tags: csv, hive, sqoop

My CSV has `<br>` and line breaks. Since openCSV serde library can not escape line breaks, my hive table breaks when I map it to this CSV.

Is there a way I can use sqoop to import data from this CSV so that I can use --drop delimiters argument to drop line break characters from the data.

if not this, Is there an alternate solution?

Comment: where does this CSV present in HDFS, LINUX or ?

Comment: @Bector: It's present on a remote server. Ofcourse I am downloading it to a server that is part of the hadoop cluster and then moving it to HDFS eventually so as to map it to a hive table

Comment: @Simran - do you know the pattern of your csv row? have you tried to explore regexserde option? ref - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38833662/6668328